# [iPhone]draw the circle around a location on google map

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am new to iPhone programming. I want to write an application using CoreLocation  and Mapkit API.
I have been able to find and add pins for the current location. Now, I am trying to draw a circle around the location, but I am not sure how to go about doing that. I'd appreciate any pointers, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I thought i have got same question with you. And i have found this questions answer, it was helped me a lot, i hope this will be help to you. 
[Drawing a Point, Line, Polygon on top of MKMapview](http://www.gisnotes.com/wordpress/2009/10/iphone-devnote-14-drawing-a-point-line-polygon-on-top-of-mkmapview/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was originally tagged iOS SDK **3.0**, but I assume that was because at the time, that was the current SDK.  If somebody is looking for the answer to this, but can use iOS 4.0+, then here's my solution.

So, I assume you have a `UIViewController`, that owns a `MKMapView`.

```
  @interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {
  @private
    MKMapView* mapView;
  }
  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;
  @end
```

and you setup your connections in *Interface Builder* (XCode now) to connect the actual `MKMapView` to the `mapView` outlet.  And then you have some variable that contains the location you want to draw a circle around: `location`.  You simply need to create a `MKCircle`, and add it to your `mapView` as an *overlay*:

```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self getTheLocationSomehow];
  CLLocationDistance radius = 50.0;   // in meters
  MKCircle* circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate: location radius: radius];
  [mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

If you want to customize the look of your circle, your view controller could implement `MKMapViewDelegate` and implement `mapView:viewForOverlay:` like so:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKCircle* circle = overlay;
    MKCircleView* circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle: circle] autorelease];
    // make the circle red with some transparency and stroke
    circleView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.25];
    circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    circleView.lineWidth = 2.0;

    return circleView;
}
```

Remember to set `mapView.delegate = self` in the view controller code (e.g. `viewDidLoad`) or graphically via *Interface Builder*.